# Unicode in Flask content-disposition header

Tags: python, http, unicode, flask

I'm trying to set the Content-Disposition header in a Flask response object to a filenam which may contain Swedish characters (åäö). My test code looks like this:

```
response =  flask.send_file(output_file_path)
response.headers[u"Content-Disposition"] = u'filename="åäö.pdf"'
```

This presents the following error:

> File "C:\Python27\Lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 401, in send_header
>       self.wfile.write("%s: %s\r\n" % (keyword, value))
>       UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 10: ordinal
>       not in range(128)

I've tried encoding, decoding and just about anything I can think about, but I just cannot get Flask to accept that I want to use Unicode (utf-8) in my header!

Answer (score 1):

See RFCs [6266](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html) for Content-Disposition and [5987](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc5987.html) for encoding. Test cases [here](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/).

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in sending http header values in utf-8. Take a look at this question [How to send non-English unicode string using HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423223/how-to-send-non-english-unicode-string-using-http-header).

Comment: The link mentions that ISO 8859-1 is ok, and since my characters are in ISO 8859-1, can I use this instead?

Comment: @monoceres Encode the string in "ISO 8859-1" and try it out. Most likely it should work fine.

Comment: No, ISO-8859-1 doesn't work reliably; some UAs default to something else (UTF-8, page encoding of referring page, or system locale).